# api-platform raise memory limit on php docker image

Tags: php, docker-compose, symfony4, api-platform.com

following the [tutorial](https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution) using docker for setting up api-platform all worked well so far. Now I'm trying to install doctrine migrations using:

`docker-compose exec php composer require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle "dev-master"`

But I'm getting:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52`

How would I raise the allow memory in that php docker container? Should I add this to api/docker/php/php.ini? I tried and did another `docker-compose up` but nothing changes.

Thanks!
Kim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1610612736 Bytes** are approximately **1.6 GB**

It's pretty uncommon that a composer invocation requires so much memory.

I guess, the real cause is not the memory limit, but if you want to increaese it anyway you should probably try this:

```
docker-compose exec php \
php -d memory_limit=2G \
/usr/bin/composer require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle
```

P.S.
`doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle`:**dev-master** could not be resolved in my installaton, so I simply omitted it